# How can I include the contents of a .txt file into a C# application and read the contents in?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have code that sends an email message to users on registration:

```
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(2, "Confirm your account", "Large amount of text here");
```

The text that I want to include is a few hundred lines of HTML which is too much for me to insert directly into my C# code. I had a suggestion to create a .txt file, embed this in my assembly, and read with Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream.

Can someone give me some suggestions on how I could go about doing this?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292

Comment: Well, you would create a text file, add it to your project, configure it as *Embedded Resource* and read it with [GetManifestResourceStream()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Looks like you're all set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The text that I want to include is a few hundred lines of HTML which
>   is too much for me to insert directly into my C# code. I had a
>   suggestion to create a .txt file, embed this in my assembly, and read
>   with Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream.

Well, you can try to follow the outlined steps. Add a new `emailBody.html` file to your project and set its `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`. Now you can read its contents:

```
var assembly = typeof(SomeClassFromTheAssemblyThatContainsTheHTML).Assembly;
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("YourProjectName.emailBody.html"))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(2, "Confirm your account", body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to leave it as a .txt file and use `File.ReadAllText()` to bring it in as a string.  Emails are generally small so this is OK.

This gives you the advantage (over an embedded resource or a hardcoded string) of being able to modify the content of the email without having to recompile your application.  It has the disadvantage of you needing to manage permissions for it.

Here's the [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here's a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711857/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-a-file-in-asp-net-mvc) for doing it in ASP.Net.